# AFNetworking HTTPClient.networkReachabilityStatusBlock not found?

Tags: afnetworking

I just downloaded the latest version of AFNetworking from github .

I drag the folder to my xCode iOS project, disable ARC for the AFNetworking files and compile . The compiler prompts an error, claiming that line 702 of `AFHTTPClient.m` has error:

```
HTTPClient.networkReachabilityStatusBlock = self.networkReachabilityStatusBlock;
```

Any advice? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found that [Getting Start Guide of AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) missed a critical step :

1. Add `SystemConfiguration.framework` to the project
2. Add the line `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` after the line `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in `Prefix.pch`

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to Shivan's point, I think you also need to add 
1) Add MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices to your project
2) Add the line #import  to your x.pch file

Otherwise AFNetworking will throw up warnings.